# requestvalidationmode="2.0" validaterequest="false" in web.config not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

I'm looking for a bit of help as this is now driving me crazy.

I have a tinyMCE text editor on my page which is populated with content which is already stored in the database as html.

eg.
`<p>first paragraph</p>
<p>second paragraph</p>`
etc, etc with no problems there.

but when I make a change in the editor and then try to update the content in the database I get the error 
**potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client**

I made all the recommended changes in the web.config

- requestvalidationmode="2.0"
- validaterequest="false"

But still get the **potentially dangerous request.form value was detected from the client** error.
This is happening in .NET 4.0 any help/advice would be great.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072950/validaterequest-false-and-net-4-problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't even try to enable this on a site-wide level in the web.config file - just do it per page, when you know specifically input data is safe:

```
<%@ Page ... ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

You can use an Umbraco control exposed specifically for this purpose from within a Template as such:

```
<umbraco:DisableRequestValidation runat="server" />
```

Comment: It was down to the above in a way. I'm using Umbraco CMS and needed to add <umbraco:DisableRequestValidation ID="DisableRequestValidation1" runat="server"/> to the top of the page to have the same effect.

Comment: @Grant Thomas, can you give a link to your blog? Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to the OP's question. The question why it was not working in the web.config, that is not answered.

Answer (score 5):

You have to post the section of web.config,

It should be,

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 3):

There was similar topic already.

[ValidateRequest="false" doesn't work in Asp.Net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673850/validaterequest-false-doesnt-work-in-asp-net-4/6365716#6365716)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your `web.config` file.

```
  <pages  validateRequest="false"></pages>
```